# KeyError in deleting rows in a dataset with drop (python)

Tags: python, dataset, delete-row

i want to delete rows with the "white" value type:
the problem I'm getting is with drop and the row

```
for row in df_red['type']:
if(row =='white'):
    df_red.drop(row,axis=0,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pandas query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) function for selecting rows where type isn't white

```
df_red = df_red.query('type!= "white"')
```

Answer (score 1):

there is also this way to get the dataframe without rows where the type is white

```
df_red = df_red[df_red.type != 'white']
```